# how to replace a char within a string with "nothing"

Tags: java, string

```
String mine = sc.next();
        String corrected = mine.replace('.', '????');
        System.out.println(corrected);
```

that's my code. let's assume that my input on String corrected is "<..><.<..>>" , and I want to replace every "." with a null space, so I get an output like "<><<>>". is there any way to do it?

Comment: just use an empty string `mine.replace('.', '')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to replace `.` with an `empty` (`""`) string, you can just do:

```
mine.replace(".", "");
```

Alternatively, you can also check [`.replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: oh this actually worked, i was using these  ' '  instead of " ", so I was getting an error. Thanks =)

Comment: `String#replace` takes either a `char` or a `CharSequence`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this to replace all occurrences of `.` with empty:

```
mine.replaceAll("\\.", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any method, you can do it like this.

```
String str = "<<.>>.<>.<<.";
String [] parts = str.split("\\.");

for(String s:parts){
    System.out.print(s);
}
```

Because I tried the method replaceAll(".", "") ;
But that method does not allow empty or null spaces in a string. 
I don't know if it's the best way, but that's what I can think of.

Comment: Split() is a method of String.